# Async jQuery POST Request in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, post, coffeescript

Using CoffeeScript, I have jQuery function that does some stuff, replaces the image source path, then tries to post asynchronously.

```
  $('.qualify_main_image').live 'click', (event) ->
     # some stuff
     $(this).find('img').attr('src', path)

     $.post(theHref)
```

I would like the image to change before making the POST request, and this works perfectly in Safari and Firefox.  However, in Chrome, it waits for a response from the POST request to change the source path of the image.

Since CoffeeScript returns the last expression in the function, I thought adding 'true' to the end of the function might help, but it doesn't.

So, am I doing something wrong?  What is going on here?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're testing this, but it might have something to do with CoffeeScript because going with straight javascript doesn't have the problem you're describing.  See the fiddle below:

```
$('.qualify_main_image').live('click', function(event){
     $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'http://www.travelblog.org/Wallpaper/pix/tb_mecsek_yellow_flower.jpg');

     $.post('/echo/json', function(data){ alert('post done.')});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dqg6A/7/

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  Wow.  So weird.  I have tried writing in Javascript,  isolating the code as much as possible, and it still keeps waiting.  I'm completely baffled.

Comment: That's strange indeed.  Even if you had async set to false, the image would still get set first.  Hm, but maybe it wouldn't give control back to the UI thread.  Oh, maybe that's it.  Check your ajax settings and make sure async: true.

Comment: Try putting your stuff in a fiddle so I can take a look.

Comment: ajax settings were fine.  after eliminating every possible js library, other than jquery, it worked, so just a matter of hunting it down.  gonna take a break.  thanks for everything.

Comment: So it turned out it wasn't working, just on the first click.  Any subsequent links would return to the same behavior.  It turns out my problem was using fricking [smackaho.st](http://tbaggery.com/2010/03/04/smack-a-ho-st.html) to use subdomains in development.  Once I switched to [pow](http://pow.cx/), all worked fine.  I even made a [screencast](http://vimeo.com/34678603) to prove I wasn't crazy.